# How can I format this output better?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I would like to pipe the output to a .csv, but when I do, I cannot add the host name, so I have settled on shooting it to a .txt, however, I don't have much latitude to manipulate the results.

The original one-liner was:

```
$([ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME").Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | select @{l='name';e={$_.name}},@{l='LastLogin';e={$_.lastlogin}} | export-csv C:\csv.csv
```

I have modified it to run against a list, however, the original code does not denote the host name... I would love to know how to do this. Here is the modified code:

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\LocalLogin.txt
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    $COMPUTER | Out-File C:\StaleLocalLogins.txt -Append
    $([ADSI]"WinNT://$COMPUTER").Children |
        where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} |
        select @{l='name';e={$_.name}},@{l='LastLogin';e={$_.lastlogin}} |
        Out-File C:\StaleLocalLogins.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: Don't have AD to check, but it might be as simple as: `select name,LastLogin,@{l='hostname';e={$computer}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you can add the hostname from **$env:COMPUTERNAME** to a later part of the script. Below is a 1 liner but spaced for ease of reading

```
$([ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME").Children |
    where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} |
    select @{l='name';e={$_.name}},@{l='LastLogin';e={$_.lastlogin}} |
    %{
        $_ |
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HostName" -Value "$env:COMPUTERNAME"
        $_ | Select-Object "HostName", "Name", "LastLogin"
     } | Export-Csv "C:\Test\test.csv"
```

This part adds a new property to the PSCustomObject that was created. It stores the hostname. Then it reorders the customobject in the order HostName, Name, LastLogin

```
%{ 
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HostName" -Value "$env:COMPUTERNAME"
    $_ | Select-Object "HostName", "Name", "LastLogin"
}
```

here it is as a one-liner

```
$([ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME").Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | select @{l='name';e={$_.name}},@{l='LastLogin';e={$_.lastlogin}} | foreach-object {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HostName" -Value "$env:COMPUTERNAME"; $_ | Select-Object "HostName", "Name", "LastLogin"} | Export-Csv "C:\scripts\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Outstanding... The only thing I changed was the $env:computername to match the variable in the foreach loop... Thanks a million brother!

Comment: $computers = Get-Content C:\Inf_IT\InputLists\input.txt

    ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
    {$([ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer").Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 
    'user'} | select @{l='name';e={$_.name}},@{l='LastLogin';e={$_.lastlogin}} | 
    foreach-object {$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 
    "HostName" 
    -Value 
    "$Computer"; $_ | Select-Object "HostName", "Name", "LastLogin"} | Export-Csv 
    "C:\inf_It\Output\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append}